# Can't connect sql server 2012 with visual studios 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2012

I keep getting this error while trying to connect the database together on the SQL CLIENT. I don't want to use OLE DB. What kind of tweaking can I do to establish this connection? Thanks. The error says "This server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported."

Answer (score 1):

Based on some quick research, it looks like you need to install SP1 for Visual Studio 2008.

[Source](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/0cd720a0-aaae-450e-88d7-e0fb22bd426c)